# Database structure (mysql): How to manage the set of specifications for every subcategory?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm building an online store using PHP and MySQL and I ran into a big dilemma.
The store has about 50 sub categories for products like: Notebooks, Netbooks, HDD, RAM, Software, Games etc) which are divided into 8 main categories (like: Laptops [Notebook, Netbook...etc]).

So now for every product, the client wants to manage the specification fields or attributes. But there are 50 set of specifications that differs from one another.
How to do this basically?

I thought I'll have to make 50 tables in database with specific fields. Another idea was to make 8 big tables that contains all the specification fields for all it's subcategory and fill it up with 'null' if the specification doesn't apply to that product... and this is wrong because when a product is inserted I don't know how to build the insert procedure to do this

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('','','','','','some specification','','some specification'....etc)`
```

How to manage the set of specifications for every subcategory?

Specifications look like this:

- Manufacturer : Sony
- Processor : Intel Core i3
- Memory : 3 GB DDR3

Specifications need to be created by the store owner... He want to set the specifications for every subcategory ... Like: The notebooks need to have this specification (manufacturer, processor, memory...etc), the hdd need to have this spec (capacity, rpm, ..etc) ... so basically he wants to create specifications and this is way complicated ... if the specifications were fixed the problem was gone.

and every product have different specifications ... (not only the name of the specification but the specification itself. like video cards, ram, hdd, ).

Comment: I suggest you read up on [database normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)

Comment: I want somehow to make a conenction between the products and the structure for the specification for that product ... :(

Comment: Is there a fixed list of specification attributes available for every product like your example for Sony ?

Comment: Yes but they need to be created by the store owner... He want to set the specifications for every subcategory ... Like: The notebooks need to have this specification (manufacturer, processor, memory...etc), the hdd need to have this spec (capacity, rpm, ..etc) ... so basically he wants to create specifications and this is way complicated ... if the specifications were fixed the problem was gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to have separate attributes table like this:

```
create table attributes(
    id bigint not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    attribute_name varchar(300),
    #any other field definitions, like data type, allowed range, etc.
)
```

And linking table category_attribute, just like that:

```
create table category_attribute(
    category_id int references category(id),
    attribute_id int references attributes(id),
    str_value varchar(1000),
    #if you are going to have different data types for each attribute you'll add it here
    #int_value int,
    #date_value timestamp ...
)
```

So you'llhave very flexible architecture that will allow you add/remove/modify attributes and category=>attribute relationships easily.

SQL for retrieving all attributes that apply to category with id =1:

```
select * 
from attributes a
join category_attribute ca on ca.attribute_id = c.id
join category c on c.id = ca.category_id
where c.id = 1 #or any other condition here
```

Also this will reduce amount of data stored.

Live example (read your question carefully and slightly changed the schema, I believe changes are obvious):

```
category(1,'Computers')
category(2,'Cell Phones')

attribute(1, 'Manufacturer')
attribute(2, 'Cost')
attribute(3, 'GSM standards')
attribute(4, 'Hard Disk capacity')

category_attribute(id=1,category=1,attribute==1)
category_attribute(id=1,category=1,attribute==2)
category_attribute(id=1,category=1,attribute==4)
category_attribute(id=1,category=2,attribute==1)
category_attribute(id=1,category=2,attribute==2)
category_attribute(id=1,category=2,attribute==3)

product(1, 'iMac', category = 1)
product(2, 'iPhone', category = 2)

product_attribute(product_id=1, category_attribute_id=1, 'Apple')
product_attribute(product_id=1, category_attribute_id=2, '$300')
product_attribute(product_id=1, category_attribute_id=4, '500Gb')
product_attribute(product_id=2, category_attribute_id=1, 'Apple')
product_attribute(product_id=2, category_attribute_id=2, '$200')
product_attribute(product_id=2, category_attribute_id=3, 'GSM 900/1800/1900')
```

Comment: can you give live example in pseudocode ... like `attributes ('1', ' manufacturer')` ... and `category_attribute ('12','1','sony')` ?

Comment: will this affect the mysql performances ... when having 10000+ products ? because the product_attribute will have about 1 milion rows ? can speed be enhanced by defining indexes ? thank you very much ...

Comment: and another question ... look at this website i found .. http://cooldown.ro/index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=product&task=view&category_id=16&product_id=1456&Itemid=196 .. if you look close the product details are in groups ... (Display -> Resolution, Colors, etc | Netword -> 3G, GPRS, etc) .. i suppose product_attribute must have another field called group ? ?? ufff

Comment: Indexes on product_attribute by product_id and category_attibute_id will speed things up. I doubt you'll have to perform index scan on the tables to get all attributes on all products. As for attributes groups - no, that group should be on attribute table.

Comment: o yes .. on attribute table .. the visitors are expected to be 1000 a day ... and the number of products will be over 10000 ? still don't you think it will need index scan ? do you think the database will do fine for over 1 milion records in product_attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to create a few tables to store all the different information, have a look at the below implementation:

Category
{
 idCetagory,
 CategoryName
}

SubCetagory
{
 idSubCategory
 SubCategoryName
 CategoryID
}

Specifications
{
 idSpecification
 SpecificationName
 SubCategoryName
}

Product 
{
 idProduct
 ProductName
 SubCategroyID
}

ProductSpecifications
{
 idProductSpec
 SpecificationID
 Value
}

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you're struggling to design the core schema of the database why reinvent the wheel here? Why not use one of the numerous free/open source off-the-shelf cart systems instead?

From personal experience I would suggest looking at [CS-Cart Community Edition](http://www.cs-cart.com/free.html), but there are many good ones to choose from.

If you don't want to do that then I suggest you start by doing some reading up on relational database design basics.

Then if you want to stick on your current route and keep the schema simple then you could look at implementing a table to store the information as metadata. Create a table something like the following:

```
ID - used as the row primary key
ProductID - foreign key to the product
Title - the heading of the specification
Value - the value of the specification
```

This is obviously very simplistic, but should point you in the right direction. It might be better to create a small set of tables to hold defined specifications but I get the impression you are going to need to keep it simple.

Comment: He don't want to use any platforms :( ... so you say I have a table for the specifications and enter line by line ? Like this (1, 50, Manufacturer, Sony) ... (2, 50, Processor, Inter core i5) ... (3, 50, Memory, 2GB) ? (where 50 is the id for the product)

Comment: You got it. I would question him why he doesn't want to use "platforms". There is no need to reinvent the wheel unless you need something very specific. You could have a very powerful, secure, flexible cart up and running in hours at very low cost by using something off the shelf, rather than weeks (at best) doing it yourself.

Comment: the store is very complex ... user rankings, reviews, adding products from excell, 500 suppliers with the same products but different codes ... but using that what you said ... how will i be able to apply filters ? and again filters are different for every product subcategory ..

Comment: Sounds pretty core cart stuff to me. One person's complex is another persons simple. Certainly CS-Cart does pretty much all of that, and what it doesn't you could always create your own add-in for.

Comment: the store is like newegg.com ... how about applying filters using the logic you mentioned ?

Comment: Looks like a fairly standard store implementation to me. You should be able to do that no trouble with most cart systems.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using following table structure:

```
category (id_category, name)
subcategory (id_subcategory, id_category, name)
subcategory_fields (id_subcategory, field_name, order)
product (id_product, id_subcategory, product_details...)
product_fields (id_product, field_name, field_value)
```

It's the most flexible approach and allows you to add/remove fields later on easily.

Example:

```
category: 
   1 "servers"
subcategory: 
   12 1 "rackmountable"
subcategory_fields:
   12 "manufacturer"
   12 "processors"
   12 "rack units"
   ...
product
   100 12 "HP DL380G6"
product_fields
   100 "manufacturer" "HP"
   100 "processors" "1"
   100 "rack units" "2"
   ...
```

To get the fields for a product:

```
SELECT pf.field_name, pf.field_value
FROM product AS p 
LEFT JOIN subcategory_fields AS sf 
    ON sf.id_subcategory = p.id_subcategory
LEFT JOIN product_fields AS pf
    ON pf.id_product = p.id_product
    AND pf.field_name = sf.field_name
```

Comment: what does subcategory_fields and product_fields do ? i can't figure it out

Comment: @pufos : `subcategory_fields` keeps the field definitions/names/keys. `product_fields` keeps the actual values.

Comment: but how to sync subcategory_fields and product_fields ??

Comment: ok i got that ... but look .. this is an exception .. for notebooks i have some specification for the processor (code, manufacturer, freq, cache ..etc) but i only want to link is the field `code` so it can retrive the info from another table ... so basically i need to have another option in `subcategory_field (id, field_name, order, link)` ?? because i don't want to add the same specifications of the processor for 100 laptops (they share only 10 or 15 processors)

Comment: @pufos this was just a skeleton example ofc. I tried to keep it simple and easy to understand. There are a lot of things you should change/add to make it work in production, including not using varchar foreign keys (field_name).

Comment: why not using varchar foreign keys (field_name)? thanks a lot ... and only one question ... for 1000 products which have 10 specifications .. there will be 10000 records in product_field ... is there a problem with databases to store this much .. of course the number will go up to 10 milions record in 2 - 3 years... does this affect the database ? can it handle it ?

Comment: @pufos let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2259/discussion-between-vlad-and-pufos)

Answer (score 0):

Break your product into components.
So for example I would have:

```
Manufacturer (id, name) 
Processor (id, p_manufacturer_id, p_name, description) 
Harddisk (id, hdd_manufacturer_id, hdd_name, description) 
RAM (id, ram_manufacturer_id, ram_name, ram_size, ram_type, description)
```

... and so on... 
Then Product would look like:

```
Product (id, manufacturer_id, processor_id, hdd_id, ram_id .. etc.)
```

Hope this helps. This of course is "normalization"!
While quering may be a pain, this would make searching a lot faster, for example, show me all laptops with 4GB ram made by Sony all you have to do is compare ID's which would be numbers.

Comment: Sorry Ali, but that is poor design, and would end up being over normalised. Following your idea you would end up with a table for each type of attribute the client wants to add. It's just not scalable.

Comment: The tables would only be created for common components, for other components you would simply have an other table along the same line that would contain the id of the manufacturer and id's of any other components relevant and then have it's own description name etc. The product table would have a ManyToMany with the OtherComponents table. you could in theory ONLY have the OtherComponents table and an other table for you ManyToMany relationship.